# MS Access 2007 Continuous Form Alternate Back Colour Screen Corruption

Tags: ms-access-2007

There should be a simple solution to this but I can't find one:

I have a continuous form with all of the controls Enabled and Locked with transparent background and frames. the Form:Detail section has an Alternate Back Colour set.

The form displays transactions for a bank account selected via a combo box in the form header. When the bank account is changed the new account's transactions are displayed.

However, if the first on-screen row displayed for the new account isn't the same colour as that for the previous account then all of the controls retain the background colour of the previously displayed row. The same screen corruption occurs on Requery or if control goes to a particular row.

Hopefully the picture below will clarify:

[Example of Alternate Back Colour problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSciw.jpg)

I've tried all sorts of things but nothing seems to solve this. The last resort is removing the alternate back colour but I really don't want to do that. Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite having tried to put this out of my mind and get on with functional stuff, it has been niggling away constantly. After a great deal of searching and generally getting distracted, I've found a really simple solution  ( at  https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=268390):

When I change accounts or go to a record, it is simply a matter of bracketing the record operation in an 'Echo False', 'Echo True' pair. So, for example:

```
    If RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
        If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > wRowNum Then
            wRecordNo = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount - wRowNum
        Else
            wRecordNo = Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
        End If
        Echo False
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, wRecordNo
        Echo True
    End If
```

or:

```
    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "WkACT_ID = " & Nz(wCurrentRecord, 0)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Echo False
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        Echo True
    End If
```

Hoorah! Hopefully that will be helpful to somebody stuck with the same cosmetic, though infuriating, problem.